# Need to insert the text at the end of the page but the table is still continuing in the next page

Tags: apache-poi

I am creating a table which is extended to next 4 pages in apache POI word and when the table is extended to the next page ,i need to insert the text at the end of first page and it needs to be happen only for the first page and rest page the text needs not to be inserted

[image]

```
 private static void addFootnoteReference() throws IOException {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    document.createParagraph().createRun().setText("This is test");
    // check to add footnotes in case of empty
    if (document.getFootnotes().isEmpty()) {
        document.createFootnotes();
    }
    // add footnote
    CTFtnEdn ctfInstance = CTFtnEdn.Factory.newInstance();
    BigInteger id = new BigInteger("0");
    ctfInstance.setId(id);
    CTP ctp = ctfInstance.addNewP();
    ctp.addNewPPr().addNewPStyle().setVal("FootnoteText");
    CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();
    ctr.addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
    ctr.addNewFootnoteRef();
    CTText cttext = ctp.addNewR().addNewT();
    cttext.setStringValue("Council Regulation (EC) No 1224/2009 of 20 November 2009 establishing a Community control system for ensuring compliance with the rules of the common fisheries policy, amending Regulations (EC) No 847/96, (EC) No 2371/2002, (EC) No 811/2004, (EC) No 768/2005, (EC) No 2115/2005, (EC) No 2166/2005, (EC) No 388/2006, (EC) No 509/2007, (EC) No 676/2007, (EC) No 1098/2007, (EC) No 1300/2008, (EC) No 1342/2008 and repealing Regulations (EEC) No 2847/93, (EC) No 1627/94 and (EC) No 1966/2006 (OJ L 343, 22.12.2009, p. 1).");
    cttext.setSpace(SpaceAttribute.Space.PRESERVE);
    // add footnote to document
    document.addFootnote(ctfInstance);
    ctr = document.getParagraphArray(0).getCTP().addNewR();
    ctr.addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
    ctr.addNewFootnoteReference().setId(id);

    // if styles dont already exist then create them
    if (document.getStyles()==null){
        document.createStyles();
    }

    CTStyle style = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);

    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(100));
    style.setStyleId("FootnoteText");
    style.addNewName().setVal("footnote text");
    style.addNewBasedOn().setVal("Normal");
    style.addNewLink().setVal("FootnoteTextChar");
    style.addNewUiPriority().setVal(new BigInteger("99"));
    style.addNewSemiHidden();
    style.addNewUnhideWhenUsed();
    CTRPr rpr = style.addNewRPr();

    rpr.addNewSz().setVal(new BigInteger("20"));
    rpr.addNewSzCs().setVal(new BigInteger("20"));

    // add style
    document.getStyles().addStyle(new XWPFStyle(style));

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.docx");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();
    document.close();
    }
```

Above code produce output in the below format :
[image: Extra 1 appearing on the top]

Comment: What your screenshot shows is a footnote. See [XWPFFootnote](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFFootnote.html): "Create a new footnote using XWPFDocument.createFootnote() or XWPFFootnotes.createFootnote()." And: "To create a reference to a footnote within a paragraph you create a run with a CTFtnEdnRef that specifies the ID of the target paragraph. The XWPFParagraph.addFootnoteReference(XWPFAbstractFootnoteEndnote) method does this for you."

Comment: Added the snippet of the code as mentioned in the above suggestion . But my question is i want to create this footnote not in all the pages but when I have created a table and the table data get extended to next page as shown in screenshot and for the first time when the table data get extended this footnote should appear.

Comment: A footnote appears only on foot of that page which contains the paragraph which has the footnote reference applied. In your case it appears on foot of that page which contains the paragraph which contains the run where `ctr.addNewFootnoteReference().setId(id)` is applied.

Comment: That's how footnotes work. A footnote is an additional remark to text on the page. So according to your screenshot there also must be that 1 somewhere in the text of the page where the footnote appears.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but when i am trying to add the footnote to the second page , i had modified ctr = document.getParagraphArray(1).getCTP().addNewR() (instead of 0 i am using 1) and it appear on the second page. But I am getting an extra 1 in the starting for the document . I don't need that extra 1 in the starting of the document and but yes in the footer message. Updated the code with the footer in the first page now . But I am not able to achieve the style as attached in the screenshot

Comment: I had attached the sample code which is used to produce the footnote and the sample is producing 1 in the top . I am not sure why?

Comment: Because using `ctr.addNewFootnoteReference().setId(id);` you are adding the footnote reference to the first and only paragraph on the page. And that paragraph is empty (contains only empty text runs).

Comment: But If i add a text as updated in the above code still the 1 appears at the top with the text like "This is test "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your screenshot shows is a footnote. See [XWPFFootnote](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFFootnote.html): "Create a new footnote using `XWPFDocument.createFootnote()` or `XWPFFootnotes.createFootnote()`." And: "To create a reference to a footnote within a paragraph you create a run with a `CTFtnEdnRef` that specifies the ID of the target paragraph. The `XWPFParagraph.addFootnoteReference(XWPFAbstractFootnoteEndnote)` method does this for you."

In `Word` a footnote appears only on foot of that page which contains the paragraph which has the footnote reference applied.  So if you wants to be the footnote on page 2, then you need applying the footnote reference to a paragraph on page 2. Behind that paragraph there will then be a number (the footnote reference) which references to the footnote which appears on the foot of the page.

Complete example for how this could look like in a table which spreads multiple pages:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFootnote;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

public class CreateWordTableMultiplePagesFootnote {

 static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
  CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
  tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
  tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
  CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
  if (tcPr != null) {
   tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
  } else {
   tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
   tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
   table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  // create footnote; will be referenced later
  XWPFFootnote footnote = document.createFootnote(); // apache poi 4.1.1
  paragraph = footnote.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The content of the footnote... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor...");

  //create table
  //2 rows 3 columns
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(2, 3);

  for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
    if (row < 1) { // header row
     table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setColor("D9D9D9"); // header row color
     table.getRow(row).setRepeatHeader(true); // header row shall repeat on new pages
    }
   }
  }

  //defining the column widths for the grid
  //column width values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  int defaultColWidth = 1*1440*6/3; // 3 columns fits to 6 inches 
  int[] colunmWidths = new int[] {
   defaultColWidth, defaultColWidth, defaultColWidth 
  };

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[0]));
  setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, colunmWidths[0]);
  //other columns
  for (int col = 1; col < colunmWidths.length; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[col]));
   setColumnWidth(table, 0, col, colunmWidths[0]);
  }

  //add more rows to fill the pages
  for (int row = 2; row < 100; row++) {
   XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.createRow();
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    tableRow.getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
   if (row == 35) { // 36th row should be in page 2
    if (tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().size() > 0 ) // get the paragraph of second cell
     paragraph = tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0); 
    else paragraph = tableRow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
    //set footnote reference
    paragraph.addFootnoteReference(footnote); // apache poi 4.1.1
   }
  }
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("create_table.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

---

Same example prepared to use with `apache  poi 3.14`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFootnote;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFootnotes;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFtnEdn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTableMultiplePagesFootnote {

 static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
  CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
  tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
  tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
  CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
  if (tcPr != null) {
   tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
  } else {
   tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
   tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
   table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  // create footnote; will be referenced later
  XWPFFootnotes footnotes = document.createFootnotes();
  CTFtnEdn ctFtnEdn = CTFtnEdn.Factory.newInstance();
  BigInteger footnoteId = BigInteger.valueOf(footnotes.getFootnotesList().size());
  ctFtnEdn.setId(footnoteId);
  XWPFFootnote footnote = footnotes.addFootnote(ctFtnEdn);
  paragraph = footnote.addNewParagraph(CTP.Factory.newInstance());
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.getCTR().addNewFootnoteRef(); 
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The content of the footnote... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor... Lorem ipsum semit dolor...");

  //create table
  //2 rows 3 columns
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(2, 3);

  for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
    if (row < 1) { // header row
     table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setColor("D9D9D9"); // header row color
     table.getRow(row).setRepeatHeader(true); // header row shall repeat on new pages
    }
   }
  }

  //defining the column widths for the grid
  //column width values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  int defaultColWidth = 1*1440*6/3; // 3 columns fits to 6 inches 
  int[] colunmWidths = new int[] {
   defaultColWidth, defaultColWidth, defaultColWidth 
  };

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[0]));
  setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, colunmWidths[0]);
  //other columns
  for (int col = 1; col < colunmWidths.length; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[col]));
   setColumnWidth(table, 0, col, colunmWidths[0]);
  }

  //add more rows to fill the pages
  for (int row = 2; row < 100; row++) {
   XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.createRow();
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    tableRow.getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
   if (row == 35) { // 36th row should be in page 2
    if (tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().size() > 0 ) // get the paragraph of second cell
     paragraph = tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0); 
    else paragraph = tableRow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
    //set footnote reference
    paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFootnoteReference().setId(footnoteId);
   }
  }
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("create_table.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

The code needs the full jar of all of the schemas ooxml-schemas or poi-ooxml-full as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025.

Comment: how can i do that in apache poi 3.14 and in that version the  //paragraph.addFootnoteReference(footnote); // apache poi 4.1.1
    paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFootnoteReference().setId(footnote.getId());  code is not present . how can i do that in apache poi 3.14 version then

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help

Comment: @Neha Mishra: I have provided the same example prepared to use with `apache  poi 3.14`.

Comment: Thanks for the help