# Trouble Compiling Apache POI 5.2.2 Code - Factory.newInstance() methods

Tags: apache-poi

Apache POI newbie.

I am trying to use Apache POI 5.2.2 to generate footnotes in a Word document.

There are some useful SO posts on this topic:

- [Need to add a footnote in between texts and the next text should be appeared in the same line not in the next line in Apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911177/need-to-add-a-footnote-in-between-texts-and-the-next-text-should-be-appeared-in)
- [Need to insert the text at the end of the page but the table is still continuing in the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753251/need-to-insert-the-text-at-the-end-of-the-page-but-the-table-is-still-continuing)

However, when I try to run those examples, I get very consistent errors on these 3 Factory.newInstance() methods:

- CTFtnEdn.Factory.newInstance();
- CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
- CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();

The compiler says:  "error: incompatible types: XmlObject cannot be converted to" either CTFtnEdn, CTStyle or CTDecimalNumber, as applicable.

Here is the full compilation error for one of these, but all 3 are similar:

Footnotes.java:68: error: incompatible types: XmlObject cannot be converted to CTFtnEdn
CTFtnEdn ctfInstance = CTFtnEdn.Factory.newInstance();

poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar is included in the compilation classpath.

I assume I have not included one or more jar files needed to get this working.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Questions about errors needs including the code which throws the error and the complete stack trace. For `apache poi` the concrete used version also needs to be known. Your mentioned classes are in  [ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas) (up to `apache poi 4`) or [poi-ooxml-full](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-full) (from `apache poi 5` on).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had conflicting jar files in the classpath.  Removing one has fixed the issue.  Axel Richter, thanks for helping me identify that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would tell more exactly what conflicting jar files in the classpath had lead to that errors. As it is now, this answer ist not very helpful.